# .NET Core 6 Authorization Handler loses context user on 2nd run

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm building a .net core 6 mvc web app with a custom AuthorizationHandler, which worked perfectly in previous .net core version. (2.0 was the last time I used it).

What is happening now with the below code is the first click, it works fine, reads the user, doesn't find them in the table, and redirects them to the no access page. But if they click it again, now the context.User.Identity.Name returns a null reference error.

I need to get the current user, look them up in the database, and then if they aren't in the correct role, redirect to the no access page. The commented out parts below were the way it used to work fine.

I first hit a problem with the redirect but found a comment somewhere saying it works differently now in .net 6 and the 2nd commented block shows the old way that didn't work and the new redirect that now works.

For the current user part, it used to just be context.User.Identity.Name that would work but now like I said, on the 2nd click it's always null. I've tried a few different ways to do this, adding the injection for httpContextAccessor which wasn't there originally but it does the same thing.

I'm thinking it's something like this part should now be different in .net 6 also like the redirect but I can't find any good examples that pull the current user. Or something like the redirect being set in the context is now changing the context for future clicks but I don't know why or what to do.

```
public class ItAdminAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ItAdminRequirement>
{
    private readonly PulseContext _context;
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;
    public ItAdminAuthorizationHandler(PulseContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ItAdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        //var userName = "";
        //if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext1)
        //{
        //    userName = httpContext1.User.Identity.Name;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
        //}
        var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        //Check the current user is in the user list.
        if (_context.Users.Any(u => u.Username.Equals(userName) && u.Active && u.UserRole.Name == "IT Admin"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/NoAccess");
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            //var redirectContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            //if (redirectContext == null) return Task.CompletedTask;
            //redirectContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("NoAccess", "Home", null);
            //context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And for reference here are the relevant lines in the Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate().AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.LoginPath = "/home/noaccess";
   });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

    options.AddPolicy("ItAdmin", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new ItAdminRequirement());
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ItAdminAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Comment: My guess is the `/noaccess` redirect simply nukes the auth cookie, so you lose the session. Can you double check in Cookies?

Comment: I cleared all the cookies for the app, and tried again, and the only one that gets set is the antiforgery one, but it stays intact when the issue happens again.

Comment: could you pls offer a reproduciable sample for troubleshooting.

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce your issue in my side and it's weird that the issue only happened when the handler is executed in the second time. running `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` for 2 times didn't result in a null referenece issue.

Comment: I don't think I can do a reproduceable sample. I decided to just have it check for null user then it just still goes to the no access page with no user set anymore. If they click to a page they have access to after that the user is found again, so whatever I guess.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I don't have any other ideas then.. sorry for it.